# How do I avoid the overhead associated with String.getBytes(Charset ch)

Tags: java, performance, character-encoding

Using `String.getBytes(Charset ch)`, allocates a new buffer, in fact it returns a `byte[]`. Is there a way to avoid this? I'd like to have a reusable byte array and have the strings encoded in this buffer.

Comment: Before you go too far down this route - do you have conclusive performance measurements which show this to be a significant problem for you?

Comment: I come for c++, allocations are evil for me

Comment: Premature optimization is a bigger evil though...

Comment: I need this to decode data coming from a tcp/ip custom protocol that could run at high speeds. I can guess that having one or more allocations for every packet may not be the best. Of course in prototype phase this doesn't matter at all. The fact is that as I come from C++ when I see this kind of things I begin worrying a lot and start seeking a solution

Comment: You are right, premature optimization is evil, but discussing on stack overflow is not! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Charset` and `CharsetEncoder` APIs directly, in particular calling [`encode(CharBuffer, ByteBuffer, boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html#encode%28java.nio.CharBuffer,%20java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20boolean%29). However, I wouldn't expect it to end up being particularly pleasant code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're like me an don't master ByteBuffer, to complement Jon's answer, you could also create your own OutputStream implementation wrapping your byte array, and use an `OutputStreamWriter` to write the String to this custom `OutputStream`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
getChars(int srcBegin, int srcEnd, char[] dst, int dstBegin) 

//Copies characters from this string into the destination character array.
```

and manage the array by yourself.

Comment: That doesn't do any encoding - that's copying *characters* around.

Comment: I think this is deprecated and however it writes to char[], not byte[], so there is no encoding at all.

Comment: `getBytes` with the same parameters is deprecated. `getChars` isn't. But yes, I forgot the encoding part...